# Product carousel, show one item on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a bootstrap snippet but I need it to be a little different.

I want it to show one item on small screens but it shows several items like this:

[image: this]

How can I change the code to satisfy my will?
( I want 4 items per row in desktop mode and 1 item per row in mobile mode)

Thanks

[Snippet Preview](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/j6QAx)

[Snippet HTML File](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pt83PvTtyQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

```
.carousel-inner {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-flex;
        height: 320px;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Just hide it on desktop mode and doesn't work properly on mobile.

Comment: @HSILA check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bp8f4dt0/
i just added above css

Comment: Yeah it works alone but when I add CSS in my file it doesn't work, Weird

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=53068734128589752904